# Crear un "turnero" para hospitales

Tags: javascript, array, formularios

estoy aprendiendo a utilizar Javascript y necesitaría ideas y ayuda.

Estoy intentando realizar un "turnero" para los hospitales, una pantalla con 6 divisiones a través de la cual al presionar un botón, el turno siguiente (cargados en una array como un objeto de clase), se presente en el primer cuadrante.

Al presionar nuevamente el botón "siguiente turno", la información del primer cuadrante se pase al segundo y se carguen los siguientes datos del array en la primer pantalla.

Hasta el momento estoy logrando con el metodo ".shift()" las primeras dos pantallas... Pero después de eso, no logro hacer el transpaso.

Me podrían dar idea de como hacer esto? Y yo voy probando!

Gracias, saludos!

Agrego el código de javascript :

```
   //Carga de clases
class Turno {
    constructor(nro,paciente,doctor,consultorio){
        this.nro = nro;
        this.paciente = paciente;
        this.doctor = doctor;
        this.consultorio = consultorio;
    }
}

//Boton para pasar turno a pantalla
$("#siguiente_paciente").click(function () { 
    $("#pantalla_individual1").empty();   //limpiar pantalla
    hora_fecha = moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); //hora
    $("#pantalla_individual1").append(
                       `<h2 class="card-title"> ${hora_fecha}                         </h2>
                        <h3 class="card-text"> Paciente: ${turnos[0].paciente}        </h3>
                        <h3 class="card-text"> Doctor: ${turnos[0].doctor}            </h3>
                        <h3 class="card-text"> Consultorio ${turnos[0].consultorio}   </h3>`);       
    turnos.shift();
    salida_datos();
 
    turno_cambio_pantalla();
}); 


//Carga de datos mediante formulario

let formulario = document.getElementById("llenado_datos");

formulario.onsubmit = function(infoEvento){
    infoEvento.preventDefault();
    carga_datos();
    salida_datos();
}   

//Carga de datos
function carga_datos(){
    let hijos = formulario.children;
    turnos.push(new Turno(turnos.lenght + 1, hijos[0].value, hijos[1].value, hijos[2].value));
    for (const hijo of hijos) {
        hijo.value ="";        
    }
}

//Salida de datos por pantalla
function salida_datos(){
    let elemento_padre = document.getElementById ("listado_turnos");
    let html = ""
    for (const turno of turnos) {
      html += ` <h3>${turno.paciente}  ${turno.doctor}  ${turno.consultorio}</h3>`;
    }   
    elemento_padre.innerHTML = html;    
}


function turno_cambio_pantalla(){
    $("#pantalla_individual2").empty()
    $("#pantalla_individual2").append(
                                       `<h2> ${hora_fecha}                          </h2>
                                        <h3> Paciente: ${turnos[0].paciente}        </h3>
                                        <h3> Doctor: ${turnos[0].doctor}            </h3>
                                        <h3> Consultorio ${turnos[0].consultorio}   </h3>`);}
```

Comment: Podrías poner el código para poder ayudarte mejor, quizá tengas todo bien planteado salvo una cosa. Edita la pregunta y pon el código :3

Comment: Agregado solamente el de Javascript.. Tengo un archivo HTML, un css y un data( de js con el array solamente)

Comment: Por cierto, la carga de datos también se hace mediante pantalla, con la función de "carga_datos"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seria bueno que en vez de poner solo el primer dato `turnos[0]` lo hagas con una variable que al dar click aumente y muestre el de la siguiente posición `turnos[i]`

```
//creando nuevos turnos
let turno = new Turno(1,"p1","doc1","cons1")
let turno2 = new Turno(2,"p2","doc2","cons2")

//agregando a una lista
let turnos = [turno,turno2]

//obteniendo el id del boton
let btn = document.getElementById("btn")

//asignandole el numero del turno
btn.setAttribute("turno",turnos[0].nro)

/*con setAtribute le asignas un atributo a un elemento
en este caso le asignamos el numero del turno*/
```

le asigno el atributo al boton ya que no tuve tiempo de probarlo con un div pero puedes hacerlo

```
//hacemos el evento del click
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    //obtenemos el atributo del nro del turno
    let nro = btn.getAttribute("turno")
    /* lo convertimos a Int y le restamos 1
    esto para usarlo como indice*/
    let i = parseInt(nro)-1
    //pasamos al siguiente turno
    let next = turnos[i+1]
    //actualizamos el atributo
    let newTurno = btn.setAttribute("turno", next+1)
    console.log(next)
    //luego puedes gregar la funcion para mostrar los datos del paciente
})
```

recuerda que al obtener el atributo lo debedes de hacer de acuerdo al elemento que se lo hayas asignado

Comment: Esto seria mas bien un comentario, podrias poner un ejemplo para que se valide como respuesta?

Comment: ok, ahora lo pongo