# Llenar inputs html mediante sql y un boton en php

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

tengo 2 inputs con nombre y apellido, la idea es que al apretar un boton se llene con el nombre y apellido del primer cliente que trae la consulta sql y a medida que voy apretando el boton vaya pasando al siguiente registro hasta que no tenga mas registros que mostrar y ahi arroje un alert indicando que no quedan mas registros para mostrar. Adjunto el codigo de lo que tengo hecho hasta el momento, el cual se basa en el evento click del boton, la consulta sql que trae los resultados de la tabla y los campos html. Si me pueden ayudar seria de gran ayuda. Desde ya muchas gracias.

EDIT: Conseguí que muestre el primer registro apretando el boton, ahora me faltaria que a medida que vaya apretandolo, ir recorriendo los siguientes registros del array hasta que no haya mas. Dejo el código con esto. Esta con array[0] justamente para probar que funciona.

```
<?php
    require_once('partials/head.php');

function datosFicha(){
        try {
            $pdo = conectar();
            $sql = "Select CTE_APE,CTE_NOM
                        From CLIENTES 
                            Where ID_SUC = 1150";
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute();
            $clientes = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $clientes;
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Error: '.$e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    $datos = datosFicha();

?>
<html>
    <body>
    <form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <label for="name" class="form-label">Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="lastname" class="form-label">Apellido</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname">
        </div>         
    </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnData">Pedir Ficha</button>
    </form>
        <script>
            let lastname = document.getElementById("lastname");
            let name = document.getElementById("name");
            $(document).ready(function(){
                let ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
                let btnData = document.getElementById("btnData");
                btnData.addEventListener("click", function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    ajax.open("POST","getDatosFicha.php",true);
                    ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
                        if(ajax.readyState == 4){
                            let array = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);
                            //console.log(array);
                            name.value = array[0].CTE_NOM;
                            lastname.value = array[0].CTE_APE;
                        }
                    }
                    ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    ajax.send();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Aclaro que si hago un var_dump sobre la variable $datos me trae toda la info de la tabla. Necesitaria poder reflejarla en los inputs y de a 1 a la vez.

Comment: te puedo decir como hacerlo pero en js, en php tambien pero harias una consulta cada vez que pidas los datos (se me ocurre otra forma en la qeu no sea asi, pero tengo que probarla)

Comment: Hola Christian, la idea es combinar php con js, por eso estaba con el evento click en el button, no se me ocurre la verdad como hacer para que no muestre siempre el mismo dato y que vaya leyendo los siguientes registros. Si tenes alguna idea, te lo voy a agradecer mucho. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Bueno una forma de hacerlo es con js, haciendo una peticion a php y guardando los valores en localStorage e ir recorriendolos cuando se presiona un boton.

```
let lastName = document.getElementById('lastname')
async function getData(){
    await fetch('') //pones la ruta del archivo php si esta en la misma pagina lo dejas asi
    .then(res=>return res.json())
    .then(result=>return result)
    .catch(err=>console.error(err))
}
//mostramos los datos en el imput que tienes
function mostrarDatos(datos,pos){
    lastName.value = datos[pos]
    // le asignamos un atributo en el cual  estara la posicion actual 
    //en la que se encuentra
    lastName.setAtribute('pos',pos) 
}

btnFicha.addEventListener("click", async function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let datos = await getData()
    mostrarDatos(datos,0)
    localStorage.setItem(“datos”, JSON.stringify(datos));
})
let btnNext= document.getElementById('btnNext')
//funcion para seguir con el siguiente en la lista
btnNext.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let datos = localStorage.getItem(“datos”);
    datos = JSON.parse(datos)
    let pos = lastName.getAtribute('pos')
    pos = parseInt(pos)
    mostrarDatos(datos,pos)
})
```

Lo unico que tienes que hacer es crear en tu html un boton con el id `btnNext` de esta forma `<button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnNext">Siguiente</button>` y en tu archivo php hacer lo siguiente

```
<?php
    require_once('partials/head.php');
    if($_GET){
        function datosFicha(){...}
    }
?>
```

Si tienes algun error o problema al implemetarlo avisa

Comment: Hola Christian, primero que nada te agradezco la respuesta, pero te comento que me arroja errores en varios lugares, por ejemplo, Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'return', este error viene de las lineas 
.then(res=>return res.json())
.then(result=>return result)

Si comento esas lineas para , me arroja el siguiente error. Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined. Sumado a que no entiendo mucho js, no puedo identificar que tendria que corregir.

Comment: Ok, podrías poner lobque supuestamente retorna el servidor ```return $clientes``` sería bueno conocer su estructura o por lo menos pon un ejemplo de lo que contiene, además olvide mencionar que al retornar los datos tienes que codificados en json con ```json_encode($clientes)```

Comment: Te paso lo que retorna la funcion datosFicha() [Imagen](https://ibb.co/v4mpzvM). Y esa linea json_encode($clientes) donde la tendria que colocar?

Comment: No puedo ver la imagen, lo que dije colócalo al retornar los datos en php ```return json_encode($clientes)```, edita tu pregunta añadiendo lo que te dije junto con la imagen que me vas a mostrar

Comment: Christian como andas? Ahi lo hice de una manera con js y me muestra el primer registro, como podria hacer para recorrer un bucle a medida que vaya apretando el boton?

Comment: Te recomiendo que veas esta pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/434378/crear-un-turnero-para-hospitales/434382#434382 ,si aún así no puedes avísame

Comment: Christian lo pude solucionar con esta pagina https://byspel.com/llenar-input-html-con-ajax-desde-php-y-mysql-database/ Te agradezco mucho por tu ayuda. Saludos